# How to select top n row from each group after group by in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with following shape

```
 open_year, open_month, type, col1, col2, ....
```

I'd like to find the top type in each (year,month) so I first find the count of each type in each (year,month)

```
freq_df = df.groupby(['open_year','open_month','type']).size().reset_index()
freq_df.columns = ['open_year','open_month','type','count']
```

Then I want to find the top n type based on their freq (e.g. count) for each (year_month). How can I do that?

I can use `nlargest` but I'm missing the type

```
freq_df.groupby(['open_year','open_month'])['count'].nlargest(5)
```

but I'm missing the column `type`

Comment: Please read [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.  It will make it more useful to the community and easier to answer.

Comment: it complaining about ''Cannot access callable attribute 'nlargest' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd recommend sorting your counts in descending order first, and you can call `GroupBy.head` after—

```
(freq_df.sort_values('count', ascending=False)
        .groupby(['open_year','open_month'], sort=False).head(5)
)
```

Comment: it then return only 5 rows, but I need to get 5 rows per (year,month)

Comment: @H.Z. The `.groupby(['open_year','open_month'], sort=False).head(5)` should take care of that.